# MyBatis parameter from HashMap

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, ibatis

In mapper interface I have:

```
ArrayList<Item> select(@Param("filterId")int filterId, @Param("filterData")HashMap<String,Object> filterData);
```

In mapper xml I have:

```
 <select id="select" parameterType="map" resultMap="RM">
        SELECT ... 
        FROM ....
        WHERE id=#{filterData["id"]}
    </select>
```

No errors but the result is not as expected (it returns empty set but I know item with such id exists). The #{filterData["id"]} seems not to work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: And what is not expected?

Comment: @Konstantin V. Salikhov It returns empty set.

Comment: Why your attr is named `sesultMap`? Have you tried to debug? What parameter value is assigned to id at query time?

Comment: @Konstantin V. Salikhov sesultMap - I made mistake while was asking my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
 <select id="select" parameterType="map" resultMap="RM">
        SELECT ... 
        FROM ....
        WHERE id=#{filterData.id}
    </select>
```

Comment: What is `filterData`? Is it a key of the map? And the `filterData.id` is the `id` attribute of the mapped value?

Comment: `filterData` is as specified in the annotation `@Param("filterData") HashMap<String,Object> filterData`, and `id` is one of its keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pure java class you can map in the `parameterType` as input to the query and return as different custom `pojo class` like this.

```
<select id="getCustomMember" parameterType="com.custom.member" resultMap="custDocMap">
        select
        customer_id, cust_start_dt, cust_type, src_sys_doc_id, 
        legal_backer_id, eenv_create_dt
        from
        web_data..wd_edoc
        where
        eenv_create_dt = #{member.date}
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your id is dynamic which is iterated from a list you can use #{filterData.${id}}