# How can I use a literal Question Mark '?' in MyBatis mapper file(Oracle SQL)?

Tags: java, sql, xml, oracle11g, mybatis

I wanna use '?' in mybatis Mpper.xml code (Oracle SQL).

It has to be just a literal question mark.

But my code runs, it takes a parameter in Map.

```
<select id="selectList" parameterType="java.util.Map">
    SELECT ... 
          ,VOL.PVOLUME_NAME || '?' || FIL.PSD_PATH_NAME || '\\' || FIL.PFILE_NAME AS FILEPATH
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
</select>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Uh, it was a terrible subject..... isn't it ;)? I'm reading it thoroughly.  your advice was very helpful to me!  thanks!

Comment: You found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829236/mybatis-parameter-from-hashmap

Comment: Oh, i'm late Pau, sorry. I have solved my problem. It wasn't about MyBatis. It was about Preparestatement. So, I didn't use Mapper.xml but just use String SQL sentence. And use setString method, it's solved. Thank you for your answer, Pau!