# HashMap Java field in Mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis

Is there a way to access the HashMap field of Java class in mybatis query

For example say I have a class below

```
Public class test{

//other fields here
…
Private Map<Integer,String> intoString = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

Public test(){
  intoString.put(1,”One”);
  intoString.put(2,”Two”);
 }

Public getIntoString(){ return intoString; }

}

}
```

Now I want to access this has any other fields

```
{

<select parameter=“test” resultMap=“…”>
select * from test
<where>
<foreach index=“key” item=“value”  collection”intoString”>
     <if test=“key == 1”>
           id1= “one”
     </if>
     <if test=“key == 2”>
           id2= “two”
     </if>
</foreach>
</where>
</select>

}
```

I managed to write code like above and it works fine.
Now my question is , as this is a map how can I access it using key 
rather than looping through it?
Something like

```
{

<select parameter=“test” resultMap=“…”>
select * from test
<where>
<if test=“#intoString[1] == One”>
           id1= “one”
 </if>
  </where>
</select>
```

Comment: Can be this the answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829236/mybatis-parameter-from-hashmap Possible duplicate

Comment: That thread uses Map as a parameterType, Ineed to use it as a field in the parameter being passed